# RDP to Microsoft Azure's virtual machines via proxy server

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, proxy, azure

I have created virtual machines in Microsoft Azure and I can't connect them from my work office, probably because it must go through the proxy server.
From my Google-ing I understand that it's impossible to connect Microsoft Azure's virtual machines via RDP because RDP doesn't supports proxy server.
Am I wrong? (please say yes:) )

Comment: You need to enable RDP proxying on your proxy server so that it proxies the RDP traffic.

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting on the correct port? Azure VMs don't use the standard 3389 port, but instead a random 5-digit number as the port number.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up teamviewer as a service(!) on your VM and then connect to it with teamviewer from your company pc. 
It's a bit laggy, but you get used to it.

Be sure to install teamviewer as a service, otherwise the rdp needs to be running on another system (your pc at home, smartphone,...) or you'll get an error that the screen can't be captured. 
This tutorial could help with this: http://ram.kossboss.com/teamviewer-error-screen-captured-moment-due-fast-user-switching/

edit: 
Summary for installation teamviewer in your VM.
Install teamviewer with the following options:
- unattended access
- advanced options for install
- setup secure password
- dont make a teamviewer account at this time (optional – if you make one it will still install teamviewer as a service)

Comment: Be sure to summarize the linked page—link-only answers aren't very useful.

Comment: Not really a link-only answer... is it? :-)

Comment: Links can become invalid over time, so it's best to post a summary of it here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to go with Remote Desktop Web Access Server?
https://turbofuture.com/computers/How-to-Remote-Desktop-to-a-Terminal-Server-via-a-Web-Proxy that I understood does the rdp sesstion via proxy.

Answer (score -1):

Is this anything like what you're trying to do? You can RDP through a proxy, only if it is enabled.
[VM Windows Azure Logon](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-log-on-windows-server/)

Comment: I assume it's not enabled because I can connect outside the VPN, but, I manage to connect to FTP via the proxy server. can I use port 21 to connect the virtual machine in Azure somehow? (let's assume that the address of the VM is XXX6677.cloudapp.net:62824)

Comment: You're in a VPN not a proxy?

Comment: Both cases, I can't connect if I in my office, and also if I connected to VPN from home, but I think that both are the same case. anyway in order to  get out I must go through the proxy server. how can I use the open ports for that?